# How to use RODBC to save dataframe to table with primary key generated at database

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rodbc

I would like to enter a data frame into an existing table in a database using an R script, and I want the table in the database to have a sequential primary key. My problem is that RODBC doesn't seem to allow the primary key constraint.

Here's the SQL for creating the table I want:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[results] (
    [ID]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]  VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [LastName]   VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [Birthday]   DATETIME      NULL,
    [CreateDate] DATETIME      NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.results] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

And a test with some R code:

```
ConnectionString1="Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=myserver; Database=TestDb; trusted_connection=yes"
ConnectionString2="Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=notmyserver; Database=TestDb; trusted_connection=yes"
db1=odbcDriverConnect(ConnectionString1)    
query="SELECT a.[firstname] as FirstName
  , a.[lastname] as LastName
  , Cast(a.[dob] as datetime) as Birthday
  , cast(a.createDate as datetime) as CreateDate
FROM [dbo].[People] a"
results=NULL
results=sqlQuery(db1,query,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
close(db1)

db2=odbcDriverConnect(ConnectionString)
sqlSave(db2, 
    results, 
    append = TRUE, 
    varTypes=c(Birthday="datetime", CreateDate="datetime"),
    colnames = FALSE,  
    rownames = FALSE,fast=FALSE)
close(db2)
```

The first part of the R code is just getting some test data into a dataframe--it works fine and it's not part of my question here (I'm just including it here so you can see what format the test data is). When I run the `sqlSave` function I get an error message:

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
>     length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

However, if I remove the primary key from the database, everything works fine with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[results] (
    [FirstName]  VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [LastName]   VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [Birthday]   DATETIME      NULL,
    [CreateDate] DATETIME      NULL
);
```

Clearly the primary key is the issue. Normally with entity framework or whatever (as I understand it), the primary key is created at the database when you enter data.

I'd like a way to append data to a table with a primary key using only an R script. Is that possible? There could already be data in the table I'm adding to, so I don't really see a way to create keys in R before trying to append to the table.

Comment: I can reproduce the error message using mysql with some syntactical modifications of your SQL code...

Comment: I've debugged `RODBC`. The problem is line 361 in https://github.com/cran/RODBC/blob/master/R/sql.R - the `data.frame` and the DB table must have exactly the same number of columns otherwise you get this error...

Comment: Bad luck, the `data.frame` ("results") and the target table must have exactly the same columns because insert statements are generated (sql.R#379). I am looking for a workaround...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is line 361 in http://github.com/cran/RODBC/blob/master/R/sql.R - the data.frame and the DB table must have exactly the same number of columns otherwise you get this error with this stacktrace:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent 
3. `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("ID", "FirstName", "LastName", 
   "Birthday", "CreateDate")) at sql.R#361
2. sqlwrite(channel, tablename, dat, verbose = verbose, fast = fast, 
   test = test, nastring = nastring) at sql.R#211
1. sqlSave(db2, results, append = TRUE, varTypes = c(Birthday = "datetime", 
    CreateDate = "datetime"), colnames = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, 
    fast = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
```

If you add the ID column to your `data.frame` you can no longer use the `autoinc` ID column so this is no solution (or workaround).

A "simple" workaround to the "same columns" limitation of `RODBC::sqlSave` is:

1. Use `sqlSave` to save the new rows into another table name
2. Send an `insert into ... select from ...` via `RODBC::sqlQuery` to append the new rows to your original table that includes the autoinc ID 
   column
3. Delete the table with the new rows again (`drop table...`)

A better option would be to use the new `odbc` package which also offers better performance through bulk-alike inserts instead of sending single `insert` statements like `RODBC` does:

https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc

Look for the function `dbWriteTable` (which is an implementation of the interface `DBI::dbWriteTable`).