# How to do a "Select * from" query using odbc

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I'm using the [odbc package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/odbc.pdf) in R, and I have an SQL Server database with a table that has a `Name` column that is `nvarchar(max)` and a `PublishStatus` column that is an integer.

This code doesn't work:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)
con_string="Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=myServer; Database=MyDatabase; trusted_connection=yes"
con=dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string =con_string)
query="select * from MyTable"
result=NULL
result=dbSendQuery(con,query) %>% dbFetch
head(result)
```

It just produces the error message

> Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n, ...) : 
>     nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2890: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Invalid Descriptor Index

If I attempt to query again, I get a different error message and as best I can tell there is no way to recover without closing R and reopening:

> Error:  'select PublishStatus,Name from MyTable'
>     nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: HY000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Connection is busy with results for another command

Because both R and R's odbc are terribly named, it's hard to google errors in this package. In [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361340/java-sql-sqlexceptionmicrosoftodbc-driver-manager-invalid-descriptor-in) it appears that the order of the columns matter, and it requires integer columns to be specified first in the query.

So this works

```
query="select PublishStatus,Name from MyTable"
result=NULL
result=dbSendQuery(con,query) %>% dbFetch
head(result)
```

but this does not:

```
query="select Name,PublishStatus from MyTable"
result=NULL
result=dbSendQuery(con,query) %>% dbFetch
head(result)
```

and the `select *` query does not.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to make it so I can do `select *` queries?
2. When I do get the `Invalid Descriptor Index` error, is there a way to recover without restarting R?

If not, this seems like an awfully bizarre deal breaker for this package.

**Edit**: using the older RODBC library, it doesn't have this flaw, even with the same ODBC driver. This works fine with `select * from` queries, and doesn't care about the order of the columns

```
library(RODBC)
con=odbcDriverConnect(ConnectionString_Hemonc)  
result=sqlQuery(con,query,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
close(con)
head(result)
```

I had previously abandoned RODBC because [it is unable (in practice) to write data to a database, as I discovered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50308125/how-to-use-rodbc-to-save-dataframe-to-table-with-primary-key-generated-at-databa).

It looks like what happened is they built `odbc` to read data faster, and a side effect of that is it's now very picky about the order in which data is read. Unfortunately, this demolishes my use case--I can't ask folks who only know basic SQL to use a tool that treats perfectly valid SQL as invalid.

I guess it's `RODBC` for reading data, `odbc` for writing data. Yikes.

**Edit 2**: I tried `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` in the connection string instead of `ODBC Driver 11` and it didn't fix the problem, but hey at least it was measurably faster.

Comment: Just idea:[R Services (In-Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/sql-server-r-services?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What happens if you wrap your column names in [ ]?

Comment: I tried [] around each column name and it has no effects

Comment: I seem to recall that the odbc driver (when I tried it) had a bug that meant that all nvarchar(max) fields needed to be the final fields in the table. So, try changing the order of the fields to `PublishStatus` and then `Name`, and then see what happens. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I can hope that the below code and the article will help you. [Getting Data From Excel and SQL Server using ODBC](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/getting-data-between-excel-and-sql-server-using-odbc/)

```
set-psdebug -strict
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop" 

$ExcelFilePath='MyPath\pubs.xlsx' #the full path of the excel workbook
if (!(Test-Path $ExcelFilePath))
 {
 Write-Error "Can't find '$($ExcelFilePath)'. Sorry, can't proceed because of this"
 exit
 }

try {
$Connection = New-Object system.data.odbc.odbcconnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = 'Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ='+$ExcelFilePath+'; Extended Properties="Mode=ReadWrite;ReadOnly=false; HDR=YES"' 
$Connection.Open()
}
catch
{
 $ex = $_.Exception
 Write-Error "whilst opening connection to $ExcelFilePath : Sorry, can't proceed because of this"
 exit
}

try { 
$Query = New-Object system.data.odbc.odbccommand
$Query.Connection = $connection
$Query.CommandText = @'
SELECT title, SUM(qty) AS sales,
 COUNT(*) AS orders
 FROM [titles$] t
 INNER JOIN [sales$] s ON t.title_id=s.title_id
 WHERE title like '%?'
 GROUP BY title
 ORDER BY SUM(qty) DESC
'@ 

$Reader = $Query.ExecuteReader([System.Data.CommandBehavior]::SequentialAccess) #get the datareader and just get the result in one gulp
}
catch
{
 $ex = $_.Exception
 Write-Error "whilst executing the query '$($Query.CommandText)' $ex.Message Sorry, but we can't proceed because of this!"
 $Reader.Close()
 $Connection.Close()
 Exit;
}

Try
{
$Counter = $Reader.FieldCount #get it just once
$result=@() #initialise the empty array of rows
 while ($Reader.Read()) {
 $Tuple = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'
 foreach ($i in (0..($Counter - 1))) {
 Add-Member `
 -InputObject $Tuple `
 -MemberType NoteProperty `
 -Name $Reader.GetName($i) `
 -Value $Reader.GetValue($i).ToString()
 }
 $Result+=$Tuple
 }
 $result | Format-Table 
 }
catch
{
 $ex = $_.Exceptio
 Write-Error "whilst reading the data from the datatable. $ex.Message"
}
$Reader.Close()
$Connection.Close()
```